# Aptana 3.4.2 auto-close matching character pairs and keyboard shortcut

Tags: aptana, aptana3

In aptana we have feature called auto-close matching character pairs, which automatic close brackets, quotas, etc. And there is tick in preferences -> aptana studio 3 -> editors:
auto-close matching character pairs for swich on/off this feature.

I changed computer to new one, downloaded and installed new aptana and found it very hard to switch this feature. tick on/off does not take a effect any more.

is there any reason meke this feature not work on fresh system?

Also, key shortcut right alt + up/down arrow (duplicate line) does not work, but in key assist it is displayed.

can anyone give me any sugestion what can I check to make auto-close matching character pairs feature and shortcut work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved: Solution for this problem was uninstall aptana and install netbeans instead.